# Can I get some clarification on the State behavioral pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, state-pattern

I'm looking into converting a big `switch` statement in my code into more manageable chunks using the `State` pattern.

I've been reading about it in the [Design Patterns book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612), and also looking at a tutorials point example [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/state_pattern.htm).

The code in that example looks wrong to me, since the author is calling the `State` functionality from outside the `Context`. Is that correct?

It's my understanding that it is the context that should be the wrapper for the states, and `State` changes should most likely be handled from within each `State` object. Otherwise it kind of defeats the purpose right?

While googling to try find the Design Patterns book `State` pattern diagram below:

[image: State Behavioral Pattern]

I came across [this example](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/State.aspx), which is much more in line with my thinking. 
So am I correct in thinking the Tutorials Point example is incorrect, and the `State` should be changed either by the states themselves, or by the `Object` that holds the `Context` with a call to `context.request()`?

Is there a valid case for doing it like in the Tutorials Point example? I can't see it myself, if you do it that way you're just going to end up with another `switch` or `if` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The code in that example looks wrong to me, since the author is calling the State functionality from outside the Context. Is that correct?**

Yes you are true, the given example poorly illustrates the *State pattern* it is much more a *Strategy* here because the Context object receives a new behavior instead of adapting it itself.

**...and the State should be changed either by the states themselves, or by the Object that holds the Context with a call to context.request()?**

Right. It is the responsibility of the State classes to set the "next state" of the context. A state machine can easily be created using the State pattern:

- Context is the machine which the current state is updated, it holds some decisional information
- Each states defines the action performed and test "transitions" to other states according to the context. If a transition occurs, the context's state is updated to a new state.

**Is there a valid case for doing it like in the Tutorials Point example? I can't see it myself, if you do it that way you're just going to end up with another switch or if statement.**

I see two reasons to update the state of the context from the outside :

- Choosing the initial state of the context (could be injected by constructor)
- Interrupt or reset the context, it is often the case in the embedded world when receiving an ISR for example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are correct the context only should have access to the state : the context as is the only client of the state .

Here is an [example](https://github.com/iluwatar/java-design-patterns/tree/master/state) of implementation of the state in java.